# Wordpress - Clearing cache

Tags: wordpress, caching

i recently made some changes to my wordpress website. In order to see those changes i need to clear the browser cache. Will users be able to see those changes without clearing the cache?
If not, then is there a way for me to clear the cache for every user that visits my site?

Comment: Are you using plugin to create cache?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about client-side caching that happens on the visitor’s device. To avoid this you'd want to investigate [cache busting](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting).

In WordPress you should be using the enqueue functions to load your scripts and styles. Both the `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` functions have parameters for version number.

For example, the following style enqueue function:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '20230508', 'all' );
```

Will produce this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='custom-style-css'  href='https://example.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/style.css?ver=20230508' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

You would just want to change the **20230508** in the above example to force user's browsers to re-download the asset and eventually *bust the cache*. So, every time you make changes to your CSS/JS files, then change the version number as well.

During development, you might want to automate this by using [filemtime()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) so that every time your file is modified, a new version number is applied.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'screen', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', array(), filemtime( get_template_directory().'/style.css' ) );
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response,  i managed to solve the problem with a plugin called WP Rocket.